# Keep unique names of places

Tags: qgis, labeling, unique-value

I have a map and I want to create a label with the unique names of places. Meaning a province may have a lot of polygons but I only want to keep one of these polygons' name (the main or biggest one is possible).

Is there a way to do that with QGIS?

This is an expression I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array(substr(Stoixeia2001_Περιγραφή,6,10))))
```

Answer (score 4):

A tip is to use the QGIS tool `Dissolve` tool by specifying `province` as the grouping field. This operation makes it possible to switch from simple polygon geometry to multi-polygon geometry.

Then, you will label your layer on the `province` field and you will have only one label per province.

[image]